# Why wont my AC turn on after adding new Honeywell wifi thermostat?

Tags: electrical

[image: Main Board][image: Old Thermostat]Bare with me here i literally know nothing about wiring besides wiring a car stereo system. Here are some pics of how my system was setup prior to me substituting my g for my c wire on the new thermostat. I then jumped the y and g wire on the main board. this is supposed to only disable the circulate function which I'm okay with. The fan turns on with the new thermostat and heat blows just fine, but nothing for the AC function. You can see that there is a seperate 2 wire (red & white) connected to the y and c terminals. I think the lead out towards the AC unit itself not the thermostat. Im not sure what to reconnect those to??? That has to be why my AC isnt turning on. Please someone help me! ☺

Comment: Can you post a photo of the new thermostat wiring, and the wiring in the air handler?

Comment: You need to add a 5th wire going from C to C on the new tstat most likely. Many new tstats require C to operate properly unless your's has specific instructions on how to wire it without a C wire. Most older tstats only had 4 wires instead of 5 going to the tstat. Yes, the 2 other wires are for the outdoor AC unit. They belong on Y and C and you jumpered Y to G so your AC won't work.

Comment: Those appear to be the "before" photos.  Do you have photos of the new wiring?

Comment: If it helps, I've [labeled the wires in the air handler](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z9tyV.jpg) for you.

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys! I will try to post my current wiring pic when I get home tonight. Topshot- I thought the same thing so I went and bought a "5 wire" cord to run them to the tstat and it seems impossible to fish the line down to the air handler. Do you have any suggestions? I thought about taping the wires together and pulling them down from the tstat to the air handler, but they are nailed to the 2 x 4's so I don't think this will work...